# Using ghci to find type

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I do something simple in ghci, like the following:

```
let x = 7 + 2
```

I expect ghci to give a response of the type that x holds, like:

```
x :: Integer
```

When I run ghci, I do not get that the above line. How do I get that response?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To show types automatically use `:set +t`:

```
μ> :set +t
μ> let x = 7 + 2
x :: Integer
μ>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the ghci `:t` command, like so:

```
Prelude> let x = 7 + 2
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 9):

To find the type of something in GHCi, you can use the `:type` command, or (as is much more common), the abbreviated `:t`. With this, you can do something like:

```
Prelude> let x = 7 + 2
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer
```