# Haskell, Simple Continuation

Tags: haskell, continuations

I am having hard time to convert a simple CPS function

This is a CPS style square function

```
-- from : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x * x

square_cps :: Int -> ((Int -> r) -> r)
square_cps = \cont -> cont (square x)
-- square_cps 3 print will write '9' out in console
```

Now, I would like to change the function arguments in reverse order

```
square_cps' :: ((Int -> r) -> r) -> Int
square_cps' = ?
```

Is it impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a minor correction to your definition of `square_cps`:

```
square_cps :: Int -> ((Int -> r) -> r)
square_cps x = \cont -> cont (square x)
          ^^^
```

Alternatively you can write:

```
square_cps x cont = cont (square x)
```

Note that this works even though the type signature makes `square_cps` look like a function of only one argument.

Now, the type signature for `square_cps'` can't work.  They way it is written it means that you could get an `Int` out of a `(Int -> r) -> r` which is a function which returns an `r`.

To flip the arguments to `square_cps`, first write this equivalent type signature:

```
square_cps :: Int -> (Int -> r) -> r
              ^      ^             ^--- result
              |       \--- second arg
              \--- first arg
```

and identify the arguments as shown. Then swapping the first and second arguments results in this signature:

```
square_cps' :: (Int -> r) -> Int -> r
square_cps' cont x = square_cps x cont
```

In general, the signature `a -> b -> c` is equivalent to `a -> (b -> c)`, i.e. the function type constructor associates to the right.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why it doesn't work. But  
'square_cps x cont = cont (square x)' is still ambiguous to me. It takes all types described in the signature and return `r`. That means, foo :: Int -> Int can be implemented like foo x y = x + y. since foo also takes all arguments and return Int. But that gives me compiler error.

Comment: When you define: `foo x y = x + y`, then `foo` has type `Int -> Int -> Int`, not `Int -> Int`. See [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659927/using-ghci-to-find-type) for how to use ghci to print the type of an expression.